# View error Can't find field 'blocked' in the following view parts composing the view of object model

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I have migrated my `OpenERP 7.0 DB` from dev to production and now everytime I try to create a new customder, I get this error:

> *View error Can't find field 'blocked' in the following view parts composing the view of object model 'res.partner':*
>   res.partner.followup.form.inherit Either you wrongly customized this
>   view, or some modules bringing those views are not compatible*

Any idea of why I see this error?

I am a magento guy so have no clue whatsoever.

Comment: Hello,It may be possible that you have added this blocked field in view part(i.e XML) but such field doesn't exists in py definition. Kindly check it and let us know.

Comment: Or you can check in ir_model_fields table or look under Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have frontend or backend instances. Make sure that:

- All code match in both instances
- Update your module
- check if column exist in your table